# Array requires that 'Element' conform to 'Equatable'

Tags: ios, swift

I am writing an iOS App in Swift. I added a class **SynchronizedArray**. On its **remove** method I am getting an error:

> Referencing instance method 'remove(obj:)' on 'Array' requires that
> 'Element' conform to 'Equatable'

I tried the solutions on the internet but not working.

**Code:**

```
 final class SynchronizedArray<Element> {
        var array: [Element]
        private let queue: DispatchQueue
        
    func remove(_ element:Element){
        queue.async(flags: .barrier) {
            self.array.remove(obj:element)
            //Error: Referencing instance method 'remove(obj:)' on 'Array' requires that 'Element' conform to 'Equatable'
        }
    }
    
}

fileprivate extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    
    // Remove first collection element that is equal to the given `object`:
    mutating func remove(obj: Element) {
        if let index = index(of: obj) {
            remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For the sake of future readers, the `array` property obviously has to be `private`. There’s little point in adding this synchronizing mechanism if the unsynchronized object is exposed. I’m presuming that the `private` qualifier was removed in the process of simplifying the code snippet for the purposes of the question...

Comment: Yes, right. removed  for the process of simplifying the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Your class should conform to `Equatable` and `index(of:)` is deprecated use `firstIndex`

```
final class SynchronizedArray<Element:Equatable> {
    var array: [Element] = []
        private let queue: DispatchQueue? = nil
        
    func remove(_ element:Element){
        queue?.async(flags: .barrier) {
            self.array.remove(obj:element)
            //Error: Referencing instance method 'remove(obj:)' on 'Array' requires that 'Element' conform to 'Equatable'
        }
    }
    
}

fileprivate extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    
    // Remove first collection element that is equal to the given `object`:
    mutating func remove(obj: Element) {
        if let index = firstIndex(of: obj) {
            remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are welcome ... as you are new on SO ... you can accept any answer that helps you ... thanks ... happy coding =)

Answer (score 0):

Simply modify  the `class SynchronizedArray` declaration and conform `Element` to `Equatable` like so,

```
final class SynchronizedArray<Element: Equatable> {
    //rest of the code...
}
```

This will resolve your initial issue.

Another issue will the pop up saying **Class 'SynchronizedArray' has no initializers**. That's because you haven't initialised the *stored properties* of the `class`. Use below code when defining the properties,

```
var array = [Element]()
private let queue = DispatchQueue.main //Initialize with whatever type of queue you want to use
```

Comment: I know you know this, but for the sake of future readers, one obviously can’t use _whatever_ queue you want. Notably, one can’t use global queues for synchronization, for example. The use of the barrier suggests that he is using a custom concurrent queue.